# What database to choose for 1TB of time series?

Tags: mysql, performance, aws, google-cloud-sql

I'm saving about 3GB per day of financial orderbook data to a database (currently Mysql). In the coming weeks, I'm going to save trade and quote (bids/asks) data too.

Data is structured, but I'm doing many searches on it, for example get all orderbooks by stock symbol (which is very slow somehow). Or get all bids/asks by symbol. Currently, a query might take 5 seconds or so (select X where ticker like Y), and the size is only 20GB. In the future, at 1TB, I'm a bit concerned regarding speed per query.

What are some recommendations for cost efficient but also performant solutions for this task? I'm currently running a Mysql database on Digitalocean. Appreciate any help, also any tips regarding what to look into (indexing, sql vs nosql, performance tips, which specific databases would be better suited).

Comment: if wont be leveraging the "relational" capabilities of a rdbms, consider a nosql solution. May also consider R data frames instead of a nosql soltuion. No silver bullets. Answers  from the community might improve if more detail were provided about how the collected data will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Any relational database will work.  1TB is huge, but feasible.

Don't use `ticker LIKE Y` unless you need to use wildcards.  Instead use `ticker = 'Y'.  Are you saying that the resultset is 20GB?  Then the *real* problem is network time.  It takes a lot of time to shovel that much data.

And have an index starting with `ticker`.  It *may* be better to have the `PRIMARY KEY` *start* with ticker.  If you would like more advice, I need to see more information.

A single row, properly indexed, will take only milliseconds to fetch.